# COUNTIF wrapped in SUM (with curly brackets used but NOT an array formula) - this works, but why?

Tags: excel

(Using 2007 - haven't tried it in 2003).

Let's say you have a column like this:

```
    A
1 BLAH
2 BLEH
```

... and you want to do a COUNTIF that returns whether BLAH or BLEH is in the cell.

So, if you put `=COUNTIF(A1,{"BLAH","BLEH"})` in `B1` it will `return 1`. 
But if you put `=COUNTIF(A2,{"BLAH","BLEH"})` in `B2` it will `return 0`.

HOWEVER --

If you put `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,{"BLAH","BLEH"}))` in `B1` it will `return 1`, and;
if you put `=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"BLAH","BLEH"}))` in `B2` it will also magically `return 1`!

I've watched the step-by-step using Evaluate Formula, and when you use SUM as a wrapper it shows that the `{"BLAH","BLEH"}` work as an array. Is this the key? Is it because SUM recognises arrays whereas COUNTIF doesn't?

I'm guessing that's the case -- but I have to say the documentation surrounding the use of curly brackets and arrays in general (outside of actual array formulas) is pretty scant.

Can anyone shed any light on what functions arrays can be used with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a part of something bigger? why don't you just use `=if(a1="Blah",1,0)` or something similar?

Comment: Because I have a column where I need it to return a 1 if it's up to about any of 10 values. There are other ways to do it (i.e. OR) - but I'm just trying to get to the bottom of the array effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNTIF(A2,{"BLAH","BLEH"})` returns an array containing the result for each value. So if you enter an array formula in B2:C2: `=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"BLAH","BLEH"}))` you will get a 0 and a 1.

When you apply the `SUM` function to the resulting array, you get the sum (kind of expected!), 1.

Note that you can also use `=COUNTIF(A2, "BLAH") + COUNTIF("BLEH")` to get the desired result and if you have many values, you can also use a vlookup, something like: `IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,rangeWithAllowedValues,1,false)),0,1)`

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. However, this didn't work: `=COUNTIFS(A2, "BLAH", "BLEH")` - it gave the "too few arguments" error (it's looking for criteria_range2 where "BLEH" is.

Comment: @EndlessLoop absolutely - my mistake - have amended.